# How to specify a generic with a where?

Tags: c#

I tried to specify this generic but I am getting multiple errors:

```
    public void AddOrUpdate(T item, V repo) where T: IAuditableTable, V: IAzureTable<TableServiceEntity>
    {
        try
        {
            V.AddOrUpdate(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ex.Errors.Add("", "Error when adding account");
            throw _ex;
        }
    }
```

For example the ":" just after the V on the first line gives an error:

```
Error   3   ; expected
```

plus other errors:

```
Error   2   Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations 
Error   6   Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   5   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   7   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   
Error   8   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Is there something obviously wrong with my generic coding ?

**Update:**

I made changes and the code now looks like this:

```
public void AddOrUpdate<T, V>(T item, V repo)
        where T : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
        where V : IAzureTable<TableServiceEntity>
    {
        try
        {
            repo.AddOrUpdate(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ex.Errors.Add("", "Error when adding account");
            throw _ex;
        }
    }
```

Calling it from the derived class:

```
    public void AddOrUpdate(Account account)
    {
        base.AddOrUpdate<Account, IAzureTable<Account>>(account, _accountRepository);
    }
```

Comment: You should probably `throw;` here rather than `throw ex;`.  Otherwise you'll toss out the original stack trace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a second `where` for `V`:

```
public void AddOrUpdate<T, V>(T item, V repo)
    where T : IAuditableTable
    where V : IAzureTable<TableServiceEntity>
```

Each `where` lists the constraints for a single type parameter. Note that I've added the type parameters to the method as well - otherwise the compiler would be looking for `T` and `V` as normal types, and wouldn't understand why you were trying to constrain them.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This is very different from a method suggested to me. I will try it out now.

Comment: I have now gone down from 8 errors to just the one error pointing to the "V.AddOrUpdate(item)" and saying: Error 3 'V' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @SamanthaJ: Right, and that's where Jamiec's answer is appropriate... unless you were trying to call a *static* method like that, which just doesn't work.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: You want to call a method on the instance, not the type, so it should be `repo.AddOrUpdate(item);`

Comment: @George - Thanks. I made the changes and I'm now going to try calling it as follows: base.AddOrUpdate<Account, IAzureTable<Account>>(account, _accountRepository);

Answer (score 5):

A few things seem wrong.

1) As @Jon said, you need separate `where` clauses

2) You need to define the generics on the method:

```
public void AddOrUpdate<T,V>(T item, V repo) where ....
```

3) You are trying to call a method on the type `V` not the instance of this type `repo`. ie, this:

```
V.AddOrUpdate(item);
```

should be

```
repo.AddOrUpdate(item);
```